# Absolute module paths in TypeScript 2

Tags: typescript

**The problem:**

I am trying to avoid relative module paths by setting the `baseUrl` option in my tsconfig.json file. Unfortunately it always says it can't find the module and I don't know why it can't find the module. Am I missing something / Do I need to do something else besides setting the `baseUrl` to my `src` folder in the tsconfig?

[image]

Actually intellisense is showing me the module's folder ('utils') when I try to import it:
[image]

**My project structure:**

root

- dist
- src

  - MyProject.ts
  - utils

    - IntHelper.ts
- tsconfig.json

**File: MyProject.ts**

```
import { IntHelper } from 'utils/IntHelper';
```

**File: IntHelper.ts**

```
export module IntHelper {
  export const xy: string = 'Test';
  export function crossSum(int: number) {
    return int; // Nonsense - ofcourse.
  }
}
```

**Tsconfig.json:**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es6",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "paths": {
      "*": [
        "node_modules/*",
        "src/types/*"
      ]
    }
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Why are you trying to avoid relative module paths?

Comment: @TimHutchison For medium+ sized projects it quickly becomes quite annoying to import modules using relative paths. Also if you decide to restructure your project or move files you would need to update all the relative paths.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your paths are incorrect relative to your baseUrl. try changing it to:

```
"baseUrl": ".",
"paths": {
  "*": ["src/*"]
}
```

Comment: hmm. are you using VS Code? did you reload the editor after making changes?

Comment: Yes I do and I haven't even thought about restarting VSCode, I was so confident it wouldn't require a restart - but I was wrong. It does work now, thanks a lot!

Comment: Hm seems like I was happy too early, now it throws a Cannot find module exception in the javascript. VSCode shows the resolve module just fine, but I can't run the transpiled javascript due to the not found module. Any ideas?